# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $S \subsetneq X$. For $r>0$, define $S^r = \{x \in X: d(x, S^c) \geq r \}$. Prove that $S^r$ is closed.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I have already proved that if $A \in X$ then for a given $r$, $\{x \in X: d(x,A) < r \}$ is open, which proves the statement since $S^r$ is the complement of the mentioned open set when $A = S^c$, but I would like a direct proof without taking that route.
My attempt:

We will show that $\overline{S^r} \subset S^r$.
Let $x \in \overline{S^r}$. Then $\forall \epsilon > 0 \ \exists \ p \in S^r$ such that $d(p,x) < \epsilon$.
Now, let $\epsilon >0$. Then, $r \leq d(p, S^c) \leq d(p,x)+d(x,S^c) < \epsilon + d(x, S^c) \implies r \leq d(x,S^c)$, so $x \in S^r$.

Now, what bugs me with this proof is that $\epsilon$ depends on the point $p$ so i'm not really saying $\forall \epsilon >0,  \ r < \epsilon+d(x,S^c)$ but rather $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \ p \in S^r$ such that $ r < \epsilon+d(x,S^c)$.

Are these two equivalent?

Comment: $\exists p \in S^{r}$ is only an intermediate step. You have proved that $r <\epsilon+d(x,S^{c})$ for all $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: $\forall x\exists y\,\phi(x)$ is of course equivalent to $\forall x\, \phi(x)$.

Comment: Yeah, but isn't my statement of the form $\forall x \ \exists \ y  \ \phi(x,y)$?

Comment: No, $\varepsilon$ doesn’t depends on $p$, instead, $p$ depends on $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Another (slightly more general) approach would be to show that the map $y\mapsto d(x,y)$ for a fixed $x\in X$ is continuous, and hence $S^r$ is closed as the preimage of a closed set under a continuous map.